# Integration Property using the product rule

Tags: calculus

Consider $g(x) = \int_0^x f(y)(y-x)dy = \int_0^x yf(y)dy - x \int_0^x f(y)dy$

I am confused about how to properly take the derivative and apply the product rule for $yf(y)$.

So,  $g'(x) = xf(x) \pm \int_0^x f(y)dy - xf(x)$

First of all, when taking the derivative are we negating or applying the integral, or both?

Secondly, I used the $\pm$ symbol because product rule tells me that it should be a plus but could integration properties would possibly make it negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with

$$g(x)=\int_0^xyf(y)dy-x\int_0^xf(y)dy$$

It is rather straightforward just derive each term of the sum on the RHS. The derivative of the first term of your sum is $xf(x)$.

For the second apply the product rule so the derivative is $u'v+uv'$ where $u=x$ and $v=\int_0^xf(y)dy$. And therefore $u'=1$ and $v'=f(x)$. Putting all this together

$$g'(x)=xf(x)-\int_0^xf(y)dy-xf(x)=-\int_0^xf(y)dy$$